# ¿Cómo solucionar estos problemas con el buscador de la opción 2 del menú principal?

Tags: dev-c++

Tengo un sistema de planillas con:

- Registro de empleados (dui, nombre, apellidos, cargo, salario)
- Mantenimiento (editar, eliminar)
- Registro de retenciones de ley (afp, isss)
- Mantenimiento (editar, eliminar)
- Informe de planillas mensuales ordenados por ( dui, nombre, apellidos, cargo, salario)
- Informe de planillas quincenales
- Registro de descuentos (días-a-descontar)

Y dos problemas:

- Dentro del mantenimiento de empleados, al hacer búsqueda del DUI a editar no lo encuentra.
- Si edito el DUI que ingresé, al almacenarse y volverlo a buscar ya no lo encuentra.

El código es muy largo y no deja cargarlo. [Aquí está](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NSKs54wupAd8p6FjPtQ30yq6PlpBrI3teAwjrdFmvbg/edit?usp=drive_link).

Comment: El código debería ir en la pregunta pero veo que es muy largo. ¿Podrías cargar solo las partes relacionadas con el problema? Por cierto, considera usar https://pastebin.com/ o alguna página similar para que el código se muestre con resaltado, o algún compilador en línea para poder ver qué entrada recibe y el resultado.